# Как сделать галерею с выбором?

Tags: jquery

Я не уверен что это так называется правильно. Задача такая: нужно при нажатии на кнопки меню сортировать содержимое.

```
<ul class="mnu-our-work">
  <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
  <li><a href=".branding">Branding</a></li>
  <li><a href=".design">Design</a></li>
  <li><a href=".development">Development</a></li>
  <li><a href=".strategy">Strategy</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="all-elem">
<div class="all-work design">
...
</div>
<div class="all-work strategy">
...
</div>
<div class="all-work development">
...
</div>
//их к примеру 9 разных div
</div>
```

То есть при нажатии кнопки Design. все остальные дивы должны стать невидимыми.

Comment: Для начала хотел бы сказать, что у вас div'ы в большинстве своем - не закрытые, точнее после описания каждого нет  > , сейчас они у вас такие:  <div , а надо <div >

Comment: все, по закрывал. но не в этом была проблема. этот пример я на спеху написал. в оригинале все нормально

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если взять за основу вашу разметку то Вы можете сделать примерно так:
(с подключенным jquery)

```
$(function () {
    var allWorkBlock = $('.all-work')

    $('.mnu-our-work a').click(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var selector = $(this).attr('href');

    // Но лучше бы там поставить звездочку.
    if (selector == '#') {
        allWorkBlock.show();
    } else {
        allWorkBlock.filter(':not(' + selector + ')').hide();
        allWorkBlock.filter(selector).show();
    }
  });
})
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/2vvzzzry/

Comment: Чуви огромное спасибо тебе. 2 дня промучился в поисках нужной инфы!!!